Cosmological perturbation theory
I am reading the paper by Mukhanov, Feldman and Brandenberger (1991) on cosmological perturbation theory. Here is the corresponding text snippet:
For reference here is the text from the paper:

I have several questions about the content discussed in the text above:

Why do we decompose the metric perturbation $\delta g_{\mu\nu}$ in scalar, vector and tensor parts? What's the advantage over just considering the independent ten components $\delta g_{00},\delta g_{01},\delta g_{02},\delta g_{03},\delta g_{11},\delta g_{12},\delta g_{13},\delta g_{22},\delta g_{23},\delta g_{33}$?

How can I see that the decomposition allows the construction of any symmetric matrix? I noticed that $\delta g_{00}= 2\phi a^2(\eta)$ and $\phi$ is a scalar, i.e., $\phi(-x)=\phi(x)$. So the $\delta g_{00}$ component is not an arbitrary function and definitively constrained. Why?

They say that $B_{|i}$ is the three dimensional covariant derivative of the scalar function $B$. How does $B_{|i}$ look like explicitly? Don't we have $B_{|i}=\partial_i B$ because $B$ is a scalar? Only for the vector and tensors we'd have for example $F_{i}^{|j}=\partial^jF_{i}+\Gamma^j_{ik}F^k$? And $\Gamma^j_{ik}=\frac{1}{2}\gamma^{jl}(\partial_i\gamma_{lk}+\partial_k\gamma_{li}-\partial_l\gamma_{ik})$. Do I understand this correctly?

If I recall correctly covariant derivatives do not commute. So $E_{|ij}\neq E_{ji}$? But we need that otherwise $\delta g_{\mu\nu}$ is not symmetric?

How are the vectors and tensors defined under 3D coordinate transformations?




At linear order in perturbation theory, the scalar, vector, and tensor equations of motion decouple. In other words, you'd generically expect the linearized Einstein equations to be ten equations, each of which involves a linear superposition of all ten components of $\delta g_{\mu\nu}$. Splitting the metric into components based on symmetries of the background means that these equations simplify, since (eg) the tensor equations of motion will only involve the two tensor fields, and not any of the vectors or scalars. This makes it easier to solve the equations.

It's not true that $\phi(-x)=\phi(x)$ in general for a scalar field. Think about the temperature in a room; is it true that the temperature in the upper front right corner must be exactly the same as the temperature as the lower back left corner at all times? $\phi(x)$ is free to take on whatever value it wants anywhere in space. What you might be thinking is that under a parity transformation, $x\rightarrow -x$, a scalar transforms as $\phi(x) \rightarrow \tilde{\phi}(x)=\phi(-x)$ and a pseduoscalar transforms as $\phi(x)\rightarrow \tilde{\phi}(x) = - \phi(-x)$. However, this is a statement about how the field transforms under parity, not about relationships between the value of the field at different points in space. Said more glibly, $=$ is not the same thing as $\rightarrow$.

Your expressions for the covariant derivative of a scalar $B$ is correct, $B_{|i}=\partial_i B$. For a vector, I'd be more careful with indices. $F_{i|j} = \partial_i F_j - \Gamma^k_{ij} F_k$, and $F_{i}^{|j}= \gamma^{aj}\left(\partial_i F_a - \Gamma^k_{ia} F_k\right)$. Your expression for the Christoffel symbols in terms of $\gamma$ looks fine.

It is true that for a general tensor field like $T_{ij}$, the covariant derivatives do not commute, $T_{ij|ab}\neq T_{ij|ba}$. However, for a scalar $B$, it turns out that $B_{|ij}=\partial_i \partial_j B - \Gamma^k_{ij} \partial_k B = B_{|ji}$. It's a special property of the second covariant derivative of a scalar function and does not imply that covariant derivatives commute more generally.

In cosmological perturbation theory, scalars, vectors, and tensors are defined in terms of how they transform under the rotational symmetry of the background FLRW metric. So under a rotation $R$,


\begin{eqnarray}
\phi(x) &\rightarrow& \phi(R^{-1} x)\\
V^i(x) &\rightarrow& R^i_{\ \ a} V^a(R^{-1}x)\\
T^{ij}(x) &\rightarrow& R^i_{\ \ a} R^j_{\ \ b} T^{ab}(R^{-1}x)
\end{eqnarray}
